# Does materializecss support both rtl and ltr in the latest release?

Tags: right-to-left, multilingual, materialize

Does materializecss support rtl in the latest release(materialize-src-v0.97.8)? I found a separate git branch where there are saas packages available for RTL support (materialize-rtl-master v0.97.0) and there is no production release . I found that in the RTL version, LTR is not supported at all. In that case, only option is to genarate  two types of css for my application taking saas files from both the version. My question is does any one has any idea how to make a single css file which can support both rtl and ltr language support? My application is using knockout js along with materialize css.

Comment: After checking all the available concept, ended up with creating two different type of css from from two version of materializecss scss. And based on locale I am loading particular css file.